# MLKMenuPopover in UITableViewCell not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, popover

I am using MLKMenuPopover in UITableViewCell not working and it's not showing correctly and also not working

There is line on the menu of cell separator

[image]

This is the code for creating the round button for popup in custom UITableViewCell

```
 _btnDelete=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [_btnDelete setFrame:CGRectMake(DeviceWidth-30, 80, 20, 20)];
        [_btnDelete setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         [_btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(btnRemoveClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.contentView addSubview:_btnDelete];
```

And this action is also custom UITableViewCell

```
-(void)btnRemoveClicked:(id)sender{
    if (self.delegate!=nil && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(delegatebtnAddressRemoveClicked:)]) {
        [self.delegate delegatebtnAddressRemoveClicked:sender];
    }
}
```

And here is the delegate method

```
-(void)delegatebtnRemoveClicked:(id)sender{

    self.menuItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"REMOVE", nil];

    NSLog(@"Button remove Clicked");
    [self.menuPopover dismissMenuPopover];
    self.menuPopover = [[MLKMenuPopover alloc] initWithFrame:MENU_POPOVER_FRAME menuItems:self.menuItems];
    self.menuPopover.menuPopoverDelegate = self;
    [self.menuPopover showInView:sender];

}
```

Comment: what is your exact problem?

Comment: my problem is that MLKmenu pop over is visible but not correctly and on tap of menu item is not working